# Select next N words using Rangy

Tags: javascript, rangy

I can select next one word using Rangy like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#select-next-one-word").click(function () {
        var selection = rangy.getSelection();
        selection.expand("word", {
            wordOptions: {
                includeTrailingSpace: true
            }
        });

        selection.collapseToEnd();
        selection.expand("word");
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4337/64/)

But how can I extend the selection to next N words?

Comment: Your JsFiddle works fine with 2 words, what does not work as expected?

Comment: When the cursor is for example on "dolor" clicking the Select next 2 words button does not select "sit amet".

Comment: Yes it selects one word every two words because I guess it overwrites the selection with the second iteration.
I'll come back to it when I get how Rangy works.

Comment: I've been reading all rangy documentation and I still have no clue. Their documentation is sick, I could have read it in chinese with the same result.

Comment: @user1835565: The Rangy docs are minimalist and assume knowledge of the DOM APIs on which Rangy is based. I agree that some worked examples would improve things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest obtaining a range from the selection, expanding it to encompass whole words, collapse it to the end, moving the whole range again two words forward and then moving the start of the range back two words using `moveStart()`. A little convoluted but achieves the desired result as I understand it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u4337/81/

Code:

```
var selection = rangy.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

// Expand to whole words and collapse
range.expand("word", {
    wordOptions: {
        includeTrailingSpace: true
    }
});

range.collapse(false);

// Move the whole range two words ahead
range.move("word", 2);

// Move the start two words back
range.moveStart("word", -2);

// Re-select the range
selection.setSingleRange(range);
```

Comment: When I hit the select next 2 words button while the cursor is on "amet", ", consectetur adipiscing" is selected.  Do you know how I can select "consectetur adipiscing " instead (ignoring the "," and including the last space)?

Comment: @jpen: I worked out a way of doing it. It's not exactly pretty though. See updated answer.

Comment: @jpen: Ah, I spoke too soon. If you put the caret in "consectetur" then it highlights the next two words correctly but then skips over "Maecenas" the next time you press the button. I'll have another think.

Comment: @jpen: Updated again and fixed now, I think, by calling `expand()` first, as it was in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! When pressing the select next 2 words button while the cursor is in "ipsum", "Select next" gets selected.  How can I restrict selections within the contenteditable div?

Comment: @jpen: You could check before re-selecting the range. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u4337/84/. I may add an option to the options object passed to `move()` and related methods.

Answer (score 2):

This should send you in the right direction. I've modified your "select-next-two-words" functionality like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#select-next-two-words").click(function () {
        var selection = rangy.getSelection();

        selection.expand("word", {
            wordOptions: {
                includeTrailingSpace: true
            }
        });
        selection.collapseToEnd();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        range.moveEnd("word", 2);
        selection.setSingleRange(range);
    });
});
```

I use `moveEnd` on the range to move the end of it two words forward. However, this won't modify the selection on the screen. You have to set the selection by using `setSingleRange` so that what's on the screen reflects the change.

For an arbitrary number of words, you should just have to change `range.moveEnd("word", 2)` to whatever number you want.